# Image gallery to resize with browser window

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to customize a wordpress website. I'm using this image gallery plugin called Foogallery. I really like all it's features, however I would like the gallery to resize just like I found out to do with a single image like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/c4qua6hf/

I tried to apply the same method from the fiddle to the gallery, but with no luck. I tried to set the height to auto and max-width and max-height to 100%.

Could it be that somewhere in all the css the foogallery comes with, somehow its blocking for my resize code? or is it not correct way to set the height to auto and max-width and max-height to 100% when it comes to a gallery?

The HTML looks like this from an example where I'm using the galley to align to images in the center of the page:

```
<div class="foogallery foogallery-container foogallery-default foogallery-lightbox-none fg-gutter-15 fg-center fg-default fg-light fg-border-thin fg-shadow-outline fg-loading-default fg-loaded-fade-in fg-custom fg-caption-hover fg-hover-fade fg-hover-zoom" id="foogallery-gallery-315" data-foogallery="{&quot;item&quot;:{&quot;showCaptionTitle&quot;:true,&quot;showCaptionDescription&quot;:true},&quot;lazy&quot;:true,&quot;src&quot;:&quot;data-src-fg&quot;,&quot;srcset&quot;:&quot;data-srcset-fg&quot;}" data-fg-common-fields="1">
    <div class="fg-item fg-type-image fg-loaded">
        <figure class="fg-item-inner"><a href="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/HANGTAG_01.png" data-attachment-id="324" class="fg-thumb" data-type="image"><span class="fg-image-wrap"><img width="452" height="678" data-src-fg="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/HANGTAG_01.png" class="fg-image" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/HANGTAG_01.png" style=""></span><span class="fg-image-overlay"></span></a>
            <figcaption class="fg-caption">
                <div class="fg-caption-inner"></div>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <div class="fg-loader"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fg-item fg-type-image fg-loaded">
        <figure class="fg-item-inner"><a href="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/HANGTAG_01@2x.png" data-attachment-id="325" class="fg-thumb" data-type="image"><span class="fg-image-wrap"><img width="452" height="678" data-src-fg="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/cache/2020/04/HANGTAG_01@2x/36442598.png" class="fg-image" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/cache/2020/04/HANGTAG_01@2x/36442598.png" style=""></span><span class="fg-image-overlay"></span></a>
            <figcaption class="fg-caption">
                <div class="fg-caption-inner"></div>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <div class="fg-loader"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.fg-default.fg-gutter-15 {
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 110px;
}

.fg-default.fg-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.foogallery {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.foogallery,
.foogallery * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.foogallery .fg-loaded .fg-image {
    z-index: 7;
}

.foogallery .fg-image {}

.fg-default .fg-image {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.fg-default .fg-image {
    border-radius: 0;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.foogallery .fg-image {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 5;
    max-width: none;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
}

.foogallery.fg-caption-hover .fg-caption .fg-caption-inner {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: I really depends on many aspects in this case. And many gallery plugins use javascript to dynamically adjust some sizes because it is very difficult to setup all sizes and adjustments just by pure css. If they use JavaScript to overwrite css values, then chances are very high that your css will be ignored. You can try to give your CSS more weight by using a more specific selector and/or using the !important extrensions for your CSS values.

Comment: You can find the FooGallery demo and details for responsive images [here](https://fooplugins.com/foogallery/wordpress-responsive-image-gallery/)

Comment: @Arno I tried with !important on multiple elements but its still does not work. I'm also not 100% sure which element and what css I should apply for it to do the resizing.

Comment: @ismi Thanks! However, I actually already went through there and I can't see how the information they give can help me in this case.

Comment: It's easier to help or advise if you can post minimal reproducible code.